# Implment factory assembly line structure with hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I want to implement an assembly line like structure where at each interval Map-Reduce is taking place using hadoop. Any suggestions over the architecture/software stack I should use?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Apache Oozie](http://incubator.apache.org/oozie/). I haven't tried Oozie, so I don't know the pros and cons of it and what customization has to be done to meet the specified requirements.

> Oozie Coordinator jobs are recurrent Oozie Workflow jobs triggered by time (frequency) and data availabilty.

Comment: I back up that Oozie is likely the right tool for this.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is : 
a) To have each interval to be HDFS directory. Let call it interval directory 
b) To have each portion of work done in previous interval to be sub-directory in the interval directory. Lets call it task directory.
c) To have some good indication (like small file) that task directory content is ready for processing.
e) To have a kind of supervisor which will run in a background, periodically check if some task directory is ready for processing and run appropriate MR job which will take this task directory as input and next interval new task directory as output.

As alternative to "complete indicator" files you can remember job ids and then ask hadoop job tracker about job statuses. It will be more precise solution, but a statefull one. So I expect it to be less reliable.
I think both precise and reliable scheduling between intervals tasks should use Zookeeper.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I was thinking if I could have some event based mechanism for state transition, it'd be nice. Any ideas on that front?

Comment: Here is a good explanation about the process of the job execution. http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/459-anatomy-of-a-mapreduce-job-run-with-hadoop/  What is interesting to you - is notification about the job completeion, which described in the end of the article (Job Completion section)

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look at Cascading - http://www.cascading.org/ - we have used that with great success to create flows (aka workflows) that perform scans, MapReduce jobs, do some math and pump the result to other outputs like an RDBMS.